# What is the best way to store information locally without local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, indexeddb

I would like to develop an app that users will be using from their phones (most likely a PWA app for now). Each user will need to store and access information that is unique to them. I'm familiar with using MySQL and MongoDB to store information, but I would rather not make the user create a username and password. My thoughts are using indexedDB or possibly saving everything to a JSON file in the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: `a JSON file in the app` how would that be specific to the user if the data is stored in the app itself? suggest you use `indexedDB`

Comment: Why have you imposed the restriction to disallow localStorage?

Comment: @Chase The information I'm storing works best as objects, which local storage doesn't handle very well from my understanding

Comment: have you try json stringify - parse in localstorage ?

Comment: @RickyOrlandoNapitupulu yeah I thought about that, but each user will be storing multiple objects that each have many key value pairs, so I was just thinking there's gotta be a better way? I'm still leaning toward indexedDB

Answer (score 0):

If there's not much data, the data is consumed by yoru server and you care about security - use cookies

I can think of only one more way to store data like that - caching. Basically, you can make your server to send `data.json` with dynamically rendered data that you beed, then you will cache it. You can use dynamic imports then to access it or via inserting  tags.

It's a tricky way so not many people expect your credentials to be stored there, although i believe localStorage is the best cross browser way to store data locally if high security isn't necessary.

Reading data fron local storage is also syncronus which some people consider to be a serious downside. I am not sure about dynamic imports of cached files and if whethers its asyncronus or not, but you might give it a try.